# integration of 1-1 increasing composite functions that preserve endpoints

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we are computing ${\int^{d}_{c} f(g(x)) dx}$.

My Question : Say that we can restrict g(x) on [a,b] so that g is strictly increasing (or decreasing) and one to one on [c,d], and that g(c)=a, g(d)=b.

Then is it possible to say that ${\int^{d}_{c} f(g(x)) dx}$ = ${\int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx}$?

My intuition suggests that if we integrate f(x) from x=a to x=b, and if there is some "stepping stone" that is unfortunately not x itself but some function of x that spits out exactly the same endpoints, while one-to-one and strictly increasing, then the two integrals would have the same values.

But I am having a hard time figuring out if this is true.

I would appreciate some help.

$\textbf{Edit :}$
I have seen in the counterexample below that this is not true in general. But perhaps different conclusions may be possible if the integral results in zero? Because in the case where the integral is not zero, there is some kind of area that might be changed to be either larger or smaller due to the composition, but wouldn't it still be zero if ${\int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx}=0$?

Comment: As the answer below shows, you are forgetting about the chain rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your 1st question is no, because (under some reasonable hypothesis, like: $f$ and $g'$ are continuous) what is true is:
$$\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(y)dy=\int_c^df(g(x))g'(x)dx.$$
Hence you may construct very simple counterexamples (e.g. $f(y)=1,g(x)=2x$).

You added a second question after having received an answer. Better edit a new post (but first try to answer it, and include your attempts in your post).

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry that I didn't edit a new post... Would be sure to do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Here is a simple counter example.  Suppose that $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = \log(x)$.  Both are 1-1 and increasing.  Notice that:
$$\int_{1}^{a} f(g(x)) dx = \int_{1}^{a} x dx = \frac{1}{2}a^2 - \frac{1}{2},$$ but
$$\int_{\log(1)}^{\log(a)} e^x dx = e^{\log(a)} - e^{\log(1)} = a.$$

The two are not equal for general $a>1$.

Comment: I should have written a new post so that I could "accept" both your answers as they were both helpful. Sorry and thanks again.